# What happens when a volcano is flooded?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

In my current game there's a volcano that will be flooded if the sea levels raise a third time.

What happens when a volcano is flooded? Can it still erupt and damage surrounding tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, a river flood only affects tiles that are marked as floodplains, and since a volcano is a mountain-only modifier, it's not possible for a flood to flood a volcano. And a coastal flood only affects Coastal Lowland tiles and doesn't affect mountains either.

Comment: But if it is marked as being on Coastal Lowland?

Comment: @Eric Lowland and mountains are mutually exclusive.

Comment: In that case, the OPs question seems misleading. Thank you for the clarification.